# WordPress - form of plugin called externally

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

i've created a plugin with a form in wordpress.
all works ok, now i would like to include the html of the form in another website (so i need the form only, without template and other things).
i was thinking to call it via ajax or embed it with an iframe.

i dont know if its the right way, but i've created a new php page in
**/wp-content/plugins/form-reg/view/form-reg-external.php** with this code:

```
<?php 
require_once('../../../../../wp-load.php');

wp_enqueue_script( 'script_init-1', get_home_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/form-reg/view/js/jquery-ui.min.js', ['jquery'], $version, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_init-1', get_home_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/form-reg/view/js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js', ['jquery'], $version, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_init-4', get_home_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/form-reg/view/js/jquery.mask.min.js', ['jquery'], $version, false );

include("form-reg-display.php");
```

i call it via **http://[www.mysite.com]/wp-content/plugins/form-reg/view/partials/form-reg-external.php**

the problem is:

1. the wp_enqueue_script is not including scripts
2. i dont know if its the right way to do that, or there is a better way to do it

thanks all who will help me!